# working around a null element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, null, sum

In my program, i "deleted" an element by turning it into a null as you can't delete an element from an array so `employee [i] = null`. However, I was wondering, if I wanted to work with the array that had a null element, like add all the numbers in the array, how do I do this without any problems?

[**UPDATE:**]

My array contains the first names, last names and ages of 4 employees, I've "deleted" one of the employees details by making it null. As per all of the suggestions I got, I tried to add all the ages using:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    if (employee[i] != null)
        sum += employee[i].getAge();
}
```

but all I get is that sum = 1.

Answer (score 1):

If the only operation you're going to perform on your array is the sum of all elements, it would make more sense to set the deleted elements to `0` instead of `null`. This way, you will not need the extra null check on every iteration.

Comment: my array does not contain only number, it contains the first names, last names and ages of 4 employees. I want to add the ages of 3 employees after I've deleted one of the employees information.

Comment: Ok, in that case you will need the null check like other answers have pointed out. Also, a cleaner way to do this is to put your Employee objects in a `List`, so you can use the `.remove()` method to delete elements in the list.

Comment: I tried that. But that just keep giving me that the sum of `employee[i].getAge` is 1.

Comment: Have you tried printing out all the (non-null) elements of the array? What does this show you?

Comment: That works fine. All the elements are printed out (except for the null one).

Answer (score 0):

`public int addAllNums(int[] nums) 
 {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
    {
       if(nums[i]!=null)sum+=nums[i];
    }
 }`

Comment: @demongolem, thanks for the edit. Didn't see that. :)

Comment: Two of the other answers are exactly what I posted. How to remove duplicate answers?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to iterate over your array and check if the current employee is not null :

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    if(employee[i] != null) {
        sum += employe[i].getNumber();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if that element is `null` or not. If it is, add to the sum. If not, do nothing.

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    if (employee[i] != null)
        sum += employee[i];
}
```

Comment: I did 
`int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
    if (employee[i] != null)
        sum += employee[i].getAge;
}` 
and the sum keeps coming up to 1 all the time.